# how can i prevent auto display pdo error in catch

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I want to use `try{} catch{}` in PDO and display custom errors in catch, but errors sent automatically to the user and I do not control them.

For example, this is my code for connecting to the database

```
class cn{
    public static function connect( $dbName=NULL ){
        try{
            if( $dbName != NULL )
                $dbName = 'dbname='.$dbName;
            $con = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=localhost;'.$dbName,
                'myuser',
                'mypass',
                [
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                ]
            );
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            if($e->getCode() == 1049)
                echo 'not find';
            elseif($e->getCode() == x)
                echo 'ABC';
            elseif($e->getCode() == y)
                echo 'DEF';
            .
            .
            .
            else
                echo 'XYZ';

        }
        return $con;
    }
}
```

But the errors are displayed as shown in the image below.

[image: error image]

Comment: You need to add the complete error message - as text - here. And are you using namespaces?

Comment: yes i use namespace; the problem is namespace?!!!

Comment: I can imagine you need to catch `\PDOExeption` instead of `PDOException` as there probably is no `PDOException` in your namespace. But that would also apply to `PDO`.

Comment: Start by not allowing the dbname to be null

Comment: for create new database, dbName = NULL

Comment: Note: you should not catch the PDOException in this class as it cannot handle a connection failure.